# Was anyone else considered to play The Highlander?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise

While watching [*Highlander*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091203/) with my son last night (his first time watching the classic), I found myself wondering if any other actors were considered/desired for the title role before it was given to [Christopher Lambert](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000483/).

Since, arguably, much of the appeal of [Connor MacLeod](https://www.imdb.com/character/ch0005520/) and the success of the movie itself stems from Lambert's portrayal, I'm wondering what might have changed with a different lead actor.

For example, it's well known that [Tom Selleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Selleck) passed on the role of [Indiana Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones), and it's kind of fun to speculate what those movies would have been like with him at the helm, instead of [Harrison Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Ford).

Comment: Kudos on watching Highlander with your son. In the intervening years, have you inflicted the sequels on him?

Comment: Wouldn't it be cool if they had made sequels. ;-)

Comment: Not related, but most of the main actors in *Mortal Kombat* (also starring Christophe Lambert, so it is kinda related to the question :p) were second choices, because the main choices either declined the roles, or got injured. For example, Christophe Lambert got Raiden's part because Sean Connery declined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Wikia - Connor MacLeod - Behind the scenes](https://highlander.wikia.com/wiki/Connor_MacLeod#Behind_the_scenes)

> The role of Connor MacLeod was originally offered to Mickey Rourke, but he turned down the role.
>
> Marc Singer was offered the role of Connor, but he turned it down due to scheduling conflicts. Singers later guest starred in the series as Caleb Cole in the season one episode "Mountain Men".

Confirmed in: ["100 Actors Who’ve Turned Down Big Movie Roles"](http://www.onlygoodmovies.com/good/movies/100/actors/)

Comment: Thanks! My google-fu clearly needs some work, though.

Answer (score -1):

Kurt Russell, Kevin Costner, Hulk Hogan, Michael Douglas, Peter Weller, Ed Harris, William Hurt and Mel Gibson were considered to play Connor Macleod.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, and thanks for your answer! But please can you add some sources to it? This answer would be much improved if it showed where you're getting your information from, and is liable to be downvoted otherwise.